# nVidia custom resolution does not work in 3d games

Tags: resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a GeForce GT 530, Windows 8.1 , driver version 382.64 and a Samsung C27H711 monitor connected over HDMI.

The monitors resolution is 2560x1440, but Windows offers only up to 1920x1080.

To fix that I created a custom resolution of 2560x1440@75 in *NVIDIA Control Panel* and it works fine for the desktop, but 3D games can not use it (it does not appear in their menu/list of available resolutions).

For example in FurMark I can select up to 1920x1080 in full screen mode and they work, but for 2560x1440 I get an error dialog saying:

```
Could not switch to fullscreen mode. Please try another resolution.
```

2560x1440 in windowed mode Works fine (in FurMark - it covers 99% of the screen, the rest is the window border).

Is there a way to make the 2560x1440 mode available for full screen 3D apps?

*News*:

After I put the computer to Sleep mode and woke it up, it showed 1024x768 and 2560x1440 was not available in the Windows Screen resolution dialog, so I rebooted it. After that it was in 1920x1080, so I opened the *NVIDIA Control Panel* and saw the 2560x1440 mode to be disabled. I enabled the *Enable resolutions not exposed by the display* options and now I can select it again for desktop. It now also works in full screen mode in FurMark, but not in the game *Trackmania Nations Forever* (TMNF) (not in the list of resolutions in game).

*Additional notes (from deleted comments)*:
The [GPU supports the resolution](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-530-oem/specifications). The image on the monitor is definitively 2560x1440 (made a photo of line by line pattern and zoomed it to check). Also it is true 75Hz (checked with [this test](https://www.testufo.com/#test=frameskipping) and a photo camera).

The game (TMNF) supports that resolution, tried it on another PC (same monitor). The used HDMI cable came with the monitor. Other PCs show 2560x1440 the moment the monitor is attached (using same HDMI cable).

*(partial) Answer*:

I created a new custom resolution: 2560x1440@60

Now TMNF lists it in the resolution selection menu. (and works after selecting, will test later for the refresh rate used)

Comment: Your GPU does not support HDMI 2.0. 2560x1440@75 Hz *cannot* work. The utmost HDMI 1.3/1.4 can support is 2560x1440@60 Hz. Why not just use DisplayPort?

Comment: @DanielB It does work. The card has no DP port (only VGA, DVI and HDMI).